# Auto_Increment After deleted data from the table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I reset the auto_increment of a field? I want it to start counting from 1 again after I delete all the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

See also [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

> It will be better to truncate table to start auto_increment from beginning of a auto_increment field:
>
> ```
> Truncate table tableName;
> ```
>
> as delete table starts auto_increment from last auto_incremented number.
>
> Second option is, if you have to delete all data then you may drop and re-create table to start auto_increment from beginning.

Comment: thanks,.if my data 1,2,3 then i delete num 2 then it still 1,3 in the table. it should num 3 change into num 2. Can you help?

Comment: It can't be changed as auto_incremented number checks last existing number. You have to do it manually.

Comment: @SitiAisyah your question says "***after I delete all the data***"

Comment: No, You may update manually update tableName Set columnName =2 where ColumnName =3